# Trying to remove the last 16 bytes that I appended onto the byte[] (which is the IV) then decrypt

Tags: java, arrays, encryption, aes

Here is my encryption class:

```
public static void encrypt(byte[] file, String password, String fileName, String dir) throws Exception {

    SecureRandom r = new SecureRandom();
    //128 bit IV generated for each file
    byte[] iv = new byte[IV_LENGTH];
    r.nextBytes(iv);
    IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(password.getBytes(), "AES");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivspec);

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dir + fileName);
    fos.write(iv);

    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);

    // Have to append IV --------

    cos.write(file);

    fos.flush();
    cos.flush();
    cos.close();
    fos.close();
}
```

This is my Decryption method:

```
public static void decrypt(byte[] file, String password, String fileName, String dir) throws Exception
{   
    // gets the IV
    int ivIndex = file.length - 16;

    byte[] truncatedFile = Arrays.copyOfRange(file, 0, file.length - 16);

    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(password.getBytes(), "AES");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, new IvParameterSpec(truncatedFile, ivIndex, 16));

    //IvParameterSpec ivspec = new IvParameterSpec(iv);
    //
    //cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, ivspec);

    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dir + fileName);
    CipherOutputStream cos = new CipherOutputStream(fos, cipher);

    cos.write(file);
    fos.flush();
    cos.flush();
    cos.close();
    fos.close();
}
```

}

As you can see I generated a 16 byte long IV that I have appended to the end of the encrypted file. This is so that I pull off the IV for decryption as well as every filing have a unique IV. I am currently getting the error:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: IV buffer too short for given offset/length combination

Aside from the problem generating the error, is my logic correct? will this work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> I generated a 16 byte long IV that I have appended to the end of the encrypted file.

No you didn't. You *pre*-pended it. Which is a better idea anyway. So you have to read it first, and then construct your `Cipher` and `CipherInputStream` and decrypt the remainder of the file input stream. You don't need to read the entire file into memory to accomplish that:

```
public static void decrypt(File file, String password) throws Exception
{
    byte[] iv = new byte[16];
    DataInputStream dis = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));
    dis.readFully(iv);

    SecretKeySpec keySpec = new SecretKeySpec(password.getBytes(), "AES");

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, keySpec, new IvParameterSpec(iv));
    CipherInputStream cis = new CipherInputStream(dis, cipher);

    // Now just read plaintext from `cis` and do whatever you want with it.

    cis.close();
}
```

Comment: How would i separate the two if the IV is at the beginning?

Comment: The way I said. Read the first 16 bytes via a `FileInputStream`, and then pass that same `FileInputStream` to a `CipherInputStream`.

Comment: Could you show an example? i keep getting errors. Its been a long day staring at the same code.